# How to build an L shaped SKPhysicsBody node in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have an L shaped polygon, which is clearly concave so I need to use multiple `SKPhysicsBody`'s. I tried a master node that contained the sprite and two child nodes that have rectangular nodes with physics bodies to make up the L. I tried this and the object isn't affected by physics.

```m
SKPhysicsBody*body1 = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(48*1, 48*3) center:CGPointMake(48*1/2, (48*3)/2)];
SKPhysicsBody*body2 = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(48*1, 48*1) center:CGPointMake(48*1/2, (48*1)/2)];
SKNode* node1 = [SKNode node];
SKNode* node2 = [SKNode node];
node1.physicsBody = body1;
node2.physicsBody = body2;
[_node addChild:node1];
[_node addChild:node2];
```

What am I missing, the master node doesn't have a physics body attached which is what I imagine might be the issue, but not sure what to put there.

I tested the sprite node with a simple rectangular body and that works fine.

Comment: SKPhysicsJointFixed..

Comment: It still doesn't do anything, I added a a point between the two child nodes and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7.1 introduced *compound physics bodies* with the method [`[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithBodies:). From the documentation:

> The shapes of the physics bodies passed into this method are used to create a new physics body whose covered area is the union of the areas of its children. These areas do not need to be contiguous. If there is space between two parts, other bodies may be able to pass between these parts. However, the physics body is treated as a single connected body, meaning that a force or impulse applied to the body affects all of the pieces as if they are held together with an indestructible frame.

In your example, you could try this (not tested):

```
SKPhysicsBody*body1 = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(48*1, 48*3) center:CGPointMake(48*1/2, (48*3)/2)];
SKPhysicsBody*body2 = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(48*1, 48*1) center:CGPointMake(48*1/2, (48*1)/2)];
SKPhysicsBody *compoundBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[body1, body2]];
_node.physicsBody = compoundBody;
```